# Docker images issue in laradoc

Tags: docker, laravel-5, laradock

I create docker-compose.yml file and create all images.
I have following images:

```
laradock_applications_1
laradock_certbot_1
laradock_memcached_1
laradock_mongo_1
laradock_mysql_1
laradock_nginx_1
laradock_php-fpm_1
laradock_rabbitmq_1
laradock_redis_1
laradock_workspace_1
```

Which Image I need to publish to host my application.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the first two containers since they're not standard in the latest Laradock v5, but the only container that should be available online with public IP address is your nginx which will act as a reverse proxy as well, so the answer is `laradock_nginx_1`